# filling a column with a default value for number of rows in file

Tags: excel, powershell

For the below code id like to add in a default value, lets call it X in the paycentre column in the final output for every row that contains information - can anyone point me in the right direction?

any help greatly appreciated.

```
$CompletedFile = "C:\Users\filepath.csv"
$path = "C:\Users\originalfile.xls"
$allstaff = @()

#define path for edited docments 
Set-Location -Path $path

#Open the Excel file for Whichever csv.  
$excelFile = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*file name*"
$excelFile = $path + $excelFile

$excel = new-object -com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} 
#Open the file
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile) 
#Activate the first worksheet
$sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1) 
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 2 row
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 3 row
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 4 row
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 5 row

$workbook.SaveAs($path + "OGEM.csv",6)
#Close workbook and save changes
$workbook.Close($true) 
#Quit Excel
$excel.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

Set-Location -Path $path


$ImportFileNoHeader = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*OGEM*" -Recurse
Clear-Content $CompletedFile

Add-Content $CompletedFile "Title,First Name,Surname,Number,DoB,Amount,EmployeeNo,Location,Paycentre"
#Fill with content from the source file, but miss the last total row

Get-Content $ImportFileNoHeader | Select-Object -SkipLast 2 |Add-Content $CompletedFile
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, below code should do what you want.

First off however, you should use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to joint paths instead of doing the string concatenation like in `$path + $excelFile` to avoid getting paths that are missing backslash characters in between the parts.

Secondly, `Get-ChildItem` returns an array of [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) and/or [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) objects, not simply filenames. To have it return only FileInfo objects (not directories) use the `-File` switch.

```
$path          = $env:USERPROFILE
$excelOut      = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'OGEM.csv'
$completedFile = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Completed-OGEM.csv'
$defaultValue  = 'X'
$filter        = '*.xlsx'
$excelFile     = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter -File | Select-Object -First 1

if ($excelFile) {
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} 
    # Open the file
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile.FullName) 
    # Activate the first worksheet
    $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1) 
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 2 row
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 3 row
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 4 row
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 5 row

    $workbook.SaveAs($excelOut,6)
    # Close workbook and save changes
    $workbook.Close($true) 
    # Quit Excel
    $excel.Quit()

    # clean-up Com objects
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

    $headers = 'Title','First Name','Surname','Number','DoB','Amount','EmployeeNo','Location'
    # import the csv file and select all the above headers plus one that is created using a calculated property
    $csv = Import-Csv -Path $excelOut -Header $headers -UseCulture | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Paycentre'; Expression = {$defaultValue}}

    Write-Host "Creating completed csv file '$completedFile'"
    $csv | Export-Csv -Path $completedFile -UseCulture -Force -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find a file using filter '$filter' in path '$path'"
}
```

<sup>I'm using the `-UseCulture` switch on Import-Csv and Export-Csv in order to match the delimiter character Excel is using on your system</sup>

Hope that helps